# How to organize Slick code into separately testable units with a configurable database?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have a codebase of several applications with a shared database that use Slick for database access. Parts of the code like common table mappings are in a common library. I want to be able to run two kinds of tests on those projects:

- tests that use the real database
- other tests that use an in-memory H2 database

I have tried several ways to organize my code to support this, but have always hit a wall at some point. My latest attempt is using the `DatabaseConfig` approach and passes around a database definition (including database, profile and table definitions) to the objects that do database operations (let's call them *Services*). This way, I can - in theory - easily test a service by passing in the database definition I want to test it with. In practice, I get problems in the interaction between services because types don't fit properly.

I have created a simplified example that shows the kind of problems I get:

```
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.Rep

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait HasProfile {
  val profile: JdbcProfile
}

trait HasId {
  val id: Rep[Long]
}

trait Table_Person {
  this: HasProfile =>

  case class PersonRow(personId: Long, lastName: String)

  import profile.api._

  class Person(tableTag: Tag) extends Table[PersonRow](tableTag, "person") with HasId {
    val personId = column[Long]("person_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    val lastName = column[String]("last_name")

    override val id = personId

    val * = (personId, lastName).mapTo[PersonRow]
  }

  lazy val Person = TableQuery[Person]
}

class DatabaseWrapper {
  private val databaseConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("PersonDatabase")

  def db = databaseConfig.db

  object Schema extends HasProfile with Table_Person {
    override val profile = databaseConfig.profile
  }

}

class PersonService(val databaseWrapper: DatabaseWrapper) {

  import databaseWrapper.Schema._

  val loadService = new LoadService(databaseWrapper)

  def load(id: Long): Future[Option[PersonRow]] = loadService.load[PersonRow](Person, id)
}

class LoadService(val databaseWrapper: DatabaseWrapper) {

  import databaseWrapper.Schema.profile.api._

  def load[R](tableQuery: TableQuery[_ <: Table[R] with HasId], id: Long): Future[Option[R]] = databaseWrapper.db.run(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
}
```

This code gives me the following compile error:

```
Error:(51, 79) type mismatch;
found   : slick.lifted.TableQuery[PersonService.this.databaseWrapper.Schema.Person]
required: PersonService.this.loadService.databaseWrapper.Schema.profile.api.TableQuery[_ <: PersonService.this.loadService.databaseWrapper.Schema.profile.api.Table[PersonService.this.databaseWrapper.Schema.PersonRow] with HasId]
(which expands to)  slick.lifted.TableQuery[_ <: PersonService.this.loadService.databaseWrapper.Schema.profile.Table[PersonService.this.databaseWrapper.Schema.PersonRow] with HasId]
def load(id: Long): Future[Option[PersonRow]] = loadService.load[PersonRow](Person, id)
```

It seems the type checker does not realize that `PersonService.this.loadService.databaseWrapper` is the same as `PersonService.this.databaseWrapper`.

Is there a way around this? Does this approach even make sense, or are there any better approaches to structure the code?

Comment: Could also have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) (instead of H2, for "real" persistence unit tests)